# Implementing a Delegate with a Named Parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I'm trying to conform to a delegate protocol written in Objective-C. One particular required method is giving me trouble. It looks like this:

```
-(void)didReceiveData:(NSData*)data Device:(DFBlunoDevice*)dev;
```

XCode's Swift autocomplete suggests that I implement like this:

```
func didReceiveData(data: NSData!, device dev: DFBlunoDevice!){...}
```

But then delivers the error:

> Does not conform to protocol 'DFBlunoDelegate'.

Notice the difference in capitalization of the named parameter "device". Changing the function to read

```
func didReceiveData(data: NSData!, Device dev: DFBlunoDevice!){...}
```

results in the new error:

> Method 'didReceiveData(*:Device:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'DFBlunoDelegate' ('didReceiveData(*:device:)')

How can I implement an Objective-C delegate method with named parameters using Swift?

Comment: The Objective-C method is named with poor capitalization. `Device:` should be `device:`. Maybe that will help when bridging to Swift.

Comment: Are you sure the first error actually occurs due to this particular method? Are there no other possible inconformances?

Comment: @luk2302 yes I am sure. If I mark only the didReceiveData as optional the compiler believes the class conforms.

Comment: @rmaddy - that works! why does the compiler want lower case letters for named parameters?

Comment: It's standard naming conventions. Only class names should start with uppercase letters. Method, variable, and parameter names should start with lowercase and use proper camel case. Even Stack Overflow expects that. Notice how it miscolors your code because of the capital `D`.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by rmaddy in the comments of the question:

> The Objective-C method is named with poor capitalization. Device:
>   should be device:. Maybe that will help when bridging to Swift.